# How to get values from nested json string by jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

```
{
    "data": {
        "info": [
            {
                "username": "john",
                "uid": "893y4t89hg98y7894th",
                "avatar": null,
                "level": null
            },
            {
                "username": "joel",
                "uid": "ui9otjry4t89hg994t",
                "avatar": null,
                "level": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the json data. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joc66cfj/).

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var str = '{"data":{"info":[{"username":"john","uid":"893y4t89hg98y7894th","avatar":null,"level":null},{"username":"joel","uid":"ui9otjry4t89hg994t","avatar":null,"level":null}]}}'; 
    str = JSON.parse(str.data.info);
    $.each(str, function(i, item){
        $(".result1").append(item.username);
        $(".result2").append(item.uid);
    });
});
```

Could someone tell me what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little wrong.
You can not access the string as an object.

```
str = JSON.parse(str.data.info); //str is string, no object
$.each(str, function(i, item){
//... it wrong


str = JSON.parse(str);//parse string, get object
$.each(str.data.info, function(i, item){
//... it right
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joc66cfj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var str = '{"data":{"info":[{"username":"john","uid":"893y4t89hg98y7894th","avatar":null,"level":null},{"username":"joel","uid":"ui9otjry4t89hg994t","avatar":null,"level":null}]}}'; 
    str = JSON.parse(str);
    $.each(str.data.info, function(i, item){
        $(".result1").append(item.username);
        $(".result2").append(item.uid);
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joc66cfj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work better - you need to parse the string before you can access an object in the JSON

```js
$(function(){
    var str = '{"data":{"info":[{"username":"john","uid":"893y4t89hg98y7894th","avatar":null,"level":null},{"username":"joel","uid":"ui9otjry4t89hg994t","avatar":null,"level":null}]}}'; 
    str = JSON.parse(str);
    var info = str.data.info;
    $.each(info, function(i, item){
        $(".result1").append(item.username);
        $(".result2").append(item.uid);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result1"></div>
<div class="result2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your parsing is wrong.You have ot make `str` a json object pefore getting values.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
var str = '{"data":{"info":[{"username":"john","uid":"893y4t89hg98y7894th","avatar":null,"level":null},{"username":"joel","uid":"ui9otjry4t89hg994t","avatar":null,"level":null}]}}'; 
str = JSON.parse(str);
var info=str['data']['info'];
console.log(info);
for(var key in info){
    $(".result1").append(info[key]['username']);
    $(".result2").append(info[key]['uid']);
}
});
```

Same updated in your fiddle.

Comment: No real need for the [] notation here.

Comment: Much harder to read in my opinion and also has a higher chance of typos with ['']

Comment: But if you want to access the keys at runtime, i think its the best way.

Comment: Sure. You are correct when you use [key] but not when you use ['data'] in my opinion

Comment: you can get it dear. Check the fiddle provided above. I updated it

Comment: I am not saying you are WRONG, just that is is harder to read.

Comment: Well for some [] is easy , for some its diffrent. :)